# How can i monitoring a linux server's resources from windows box?

Tags: windows, linux, monitoring, widget, snmp

I have a few linux server and want to monitoring their resources from my windows desktop computer.

It'd be great if the application is/have/can (etc...);

- easy-to-use.
- widget-like looking on desktop.
- warning on high resource using.

Answer (score 1):

x11 server on your desktop plus + xosview would be a start, anyway this belongs on serverfault ;)

Comment: It is not an option actually because the server is used as a web server and x-server is a definetely a resource waster for a web server.

Answer (score 1):

[GKrellm](http://srcbox.net/projects/gkrellm/) is a nifty little widget which will hook into a Linux server and monitor a suite of different stats. The main GKrellm site is [here](http://members.dslextreme.com/users/billw/gkrellm/gkrellm.html).